# How to start Selenium with Socks5 proxy that connects with login and password

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to run Selenium Webdriver with socks5 proxy that has username and password to work with it.

I am trying to do it with built-in solution in Selenium, but it doesn't use my proxy (i check it on whatsmyip site).

```
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.socks_proxy = "socks5://1.2.3.4:59101"
proxy.socks_username = "username"
proxy.socks_password = "password"
proxy.socks_version = 5

desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
proxy.add_to_capabilities(desired_capabilities)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe",
    options=options,
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
)
```

Already tried to use selenium-ware and other solutions from chatgpt and google, nothing works
Changing url to socks5://username:password@1.2.3.4:59101 doesn't work too

Comment: If my memory dont fails, to solve that problem on my work we make a "proxy-server" that do the authentication and use that "proxy-server" ip:port on chrome

Answer (score 0):

For socks5 proxy with auth, you can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase :

`pip install seleniumbase`, and run this with `python` after setting variables:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(proxy="USER:PASS@socks5://IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Did you test this code? It doesnt work :)
Still get err socks connection

Comment: Might be an issue with your proxy server then.

Comment: I see that you are main contributor of this library, but I have tested many proxies with authorization and no one worked. Selenium driver at default doesnt support socks4/5 proxies with auth, thats why I'm here. I can give you proxy for test if u want.